# How to get post ID of the current page/post inside a widget?

Tags: posts, widgets

I'm trying hard to get the post ID of the current post/page inside a widget class but doesn't work, I know there's get_the_ID() and some other options but not a single works inside a widget. Here's my code:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {


   global $wp_query;

   $thePostID = $wp_query->post->ID;
   echo 'Post ID is:' . $thePostID;

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make use of [`get_queried_object()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) here, which is a wrapper for `$wp_query` and returns the whole post metadata.

Here's a sample code:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();

if ( $queried_object ) {
    $post_id = $queried_object->ID;
    echo $post_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
global $post;
setup_postdata( $post );
echo "Post's ID: " . get_the_ID();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To just get the `ID` [get_queried_object_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/)

Of course, too late but may help others who is looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function widget($args, $instance) {
         global $post;
         echo $post->ID;

 }
```

Comment: Can you explain the code as how it helps the OP

Comment: can yo explain what you want then i can help you.